# Как посчитать Pixel Per Line (ширину изображения)

Tags: c++, opencv, directx, gdi

У меня в памяти чужого процесса есть изображение. Я знаю начальный адрес, мне нужно узнать ширину этого изображения, если 1 byte = 1 pixel. По адрессу вот такая структура:

```
address:        int:            hex:
0x1FF05666000 = 92147712    |   0x57E1000
0x1FF05666004 = 511         |   0x1FF
0x1FF05666008 = 88346624    |   0x5441000
0x1FF0566600С = 511         |   0x1FF
0x1FF05666010 = 0
0x1FF05666014 = 0
0x1FF05666018 = 0
0x1FF0566601С = 0
0x1FF05666020 = 1544192     |   0x179000 //размер 1FF05666000 + 179000 = последний пиксель
0x1FF05666024 = 0
0x1FF05666028 = 1572864     |   0x180000
0x1FF0566602С = 0
0x1FF05666030 = 0
0x1FF05666034 = 0
0x1FF05666038 = 521797146   |   0x1F19FE1A
0x1FF0566603С = 67108864    |   0x4000000
0x1FF05666040 = 0
0x1FF05666044 = 0
0x1FF05666048 = 0
0x1FF0566604С = 0
0x1FF05666050 = 0
0x1FF05666054 = 0
0x1FF05666058 = 90595392    |   0x5666040
0x1FF0566605С = 511         |   0x1FF
0x1FF05666060 = 0 //первый пиксель
```

Я знаю что сейчас ширина изображения равна 828 пикселей. Вопрос следующий как получилась цифра 828, если 1 byte = 1 pixel? Как посчитать на основании данных выше ширину изображения?

Comment: А почему решили, что 1 байт = 1 пиксель?

Comment: в моём случае я знаю что 1 байт = 1 пиксель, там в изображении всего несколько цветов (2-3) и я вижу в памяти этот массив так что это 100%